# How to bundle dc.js plot with rollup?

Tags: dc.js, rollupjs

I'm working on an application that uses d3 to create some interactive
maps and have successfully used rollup to bundle the javascript. I
have used dc.js in the past, and wanted to incorporate a bunch of dc.js plots
into the application.  However I have been unable to figure out how to get
dc.js to work with rollup. It is mentioned in some discussions in the
dc.js issue tracker ([example](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/1175)) , so I'm pretty sure it can be done.  I'm hoping
someone can point out my mistake.

I have create a minimal example that demonstrates the issue(s) using a
single, simple dc.barChart modified from here: [dc Bar Chart Example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/bar.html.).  When
I call `rollup -c`, bundle.js is created but:

1. a warning that "dc.barChart is not exported by node_modules\dc\dc.js" and
2. when the html page loads, the figure does not appear and the
   console says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot
   add property box, object is not extensible".  "box" appears to be
   referring to d3.box, but I have no idea why.

Here is my minimal index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>dc.js Rollup</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/3.0.7/dc.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="container" class="container" >
            <h3>A dc.js bar graph:</h3>
            <div id="test"></div>
            <p>modified from <a href="https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/bar.html">this example</a>.</p>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Here is main.js:

```
import * as d3  from 'd3';
import crossfilter from 'crossfilter2';
import * as dc from 'dc';


let chart = dc.barChart('#test');

d3.csv('morley.csv').then(function(experiments) {
  experiments.forEach(function(x) {
    x.Speed = +x.Speed;
  });

  let ndx  = crossfilter(experiments);
  let runDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return +d.Run;});
  let speedSumGroup = runDimension
      .group().reduceSum(function(d)
                         {return d.Speed * d.Run / 1000;});

  chart
    .width(768)
    .height(480)
    .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([6,20]))
    .brushOn(false)
    .yAxisLabel('This is the Y Axis!')
    .dimension(runDimension)
    .group(speedSumGroup)
    .on('renderlet', function(chart) {
      chart.selectAll('rect').on('click', function(d) {
        console.log('click!', d);
      });
    });

  chart.render();

});

export { dc, d3, crossfilter };
```

and finally here is rollup.config.js:

```
import  resolve  from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import  globals  from 'rollup-plugin-node-globals';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import json from 'rollup-plugin-json';
import sourcemaps from 'rollup-plugin-sourcemaps';


function onwarn (warning, warn) {
  if (warning.code === 'CIRCULAR_DEPENDENCY') return;
  warn(warning);
}


export default {
  input: 'main.js',

  output: {
    name: 'dcjs_rollup',
    file: 'bundle.js',
    format: 'iife',
    sourceMap: true,
    globals: {
      'd3': 'd3',
      'dc': 'dc',
      'crossfilter2': 'crossfilter'
    }

  },
  onwarn: onwarn,
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      jsnext: true,
      main: true,
      browser: true
    }),
    sourcemaps(),
    json(),
    commonjs(),
    globals(),

  ]
};
```

I'm hoping that I am missing something simple in my configuration
file or just need to include another plugin,  but I am completely out
of ideas.

Any suggestions?

Adam

Comment: Hi Adam, this is really a bug report, so I [opened an issue here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1489). Looks like the correct way to extend the d3 symbol has changed but we are still doing this the old way.